# How do I add the content of an environment variable to a file in windows batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Under windows, I would like to add the content of an environment variable, say `JOB_NUMBER` to a file, say `C:\job_numbers.txt`.

Example: The file is empty and `JOB_NUMBER` contains the value 100. I want the content of the file `C:\job_numbers.txt` then to be

```
100
```

When I repeat this step and `JOB_NUMBER` now contains the value 101, I want the content of the file `C:\job_numbers.txt` then to be

```
100
101
```

(so each new addition in a new line).

How can I achieve this in windows batch without a complicated mechanism and without installing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>"C:\job_numbers.txt" echo %job_number%
```

Note that the quotes are only required if the filename contains spaces; they're harmless otherwise.

Comment: This does not work, as windows cannot find the 'command' "C:\job_numbers.txt".

Comment: The `>` symbols are important. They tell windows to append the value `echo`ed to the file. One `>` would create a new file with that name, two appends to any existing file or creates a new file if it does not already exist. Your report indicates that you have omitted the `>>`.

Comment: Oh ok! I misread those symbols as the standard angles at the begin of each line. Knowing that, your suggestion indeed seems to work as I was hoping to. Thanks..